# CrafterCMS Asset Upload Error due to size

Tags: crafter-cms

I am trying to upload an image of size 7 MB under static assets of Crafter Studio  to AWS S3 bucket but get: "Upload Error". However, I can still upload images up to 2 MB size. Is there a size limit set somewhere in the configuration?

Many thanks in advance.

Abdel